# How to explicitly define the AWS credentials for MLFlow when using AWS S3 as artifact store

Tags: amazon-s3, mlflow

so I'm using a MLFlow tracking server where I define a S3 bucket to be the artifact stores. Right now, MLFlow by default is getting the credentials to write/read the bucket via my `default` profile in `.aws/credentials` but I do have a `staging` and `dev` profile as well. So my question is is there a way to explicitly tells MLFlow to use the `staging` or `dev` profile credentials instead of `default`? I can't seem to find this info anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> To allow the server and clients to access the artifact location, you should configure your cloud provider credentials as normal. For example, for S3, you can set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables, use an IAM role, or configure a default profile in ~/.aws/credentials. See Set up AWS Credentials and Region for Development for more info.

Apparently there is no option to set another profile. I use aws-vault so it is easy to change profiles